# Can I receive SMS status without a URL in Twilio API?

Tags: c#, url, sms, twilio

This question relates to Twilio and the API for it (C#).

I do not have a website nor a web application, just a need to send SMS notifications to my own private mobile when something happens on a server (NOT a webserver). I have already, successfully, sent SMS to my mobile from a C# dll. I want to check the status of the message. All the references imply website/web application use cases, and getting the status using a URL.

How do I do this in C#? Is there an example of the suggestion made [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9430003/how-to-get-notified-when-sms-status-changes-from-queued-to-sent)? No PHP or other web servery technology.

Comment: You can use Twilio's C# client to send a message.

Comment: I don't think you can lookup the status of an SMS like that. You need to wait for the callback to hit your server.

Comment: Hi Greg. A little more info would be good? Cheers

Comment: You can *send* an SMS with a simple HTTP request from just about any application/server. You can't *receive* an SMS without setting the URL and having it hit a server somewhere. Here's an example that should help: http://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/csharp/sms/sending-via-rest

Comment: @CaseySoftware: I dont want to _receive_ an SMS, just the (updated) response to _sending_ one, because when initially sent the SMSMessage object has a status of "queued". I need to find out through the DLL whether the notifications been sent, or it has failed.

Answer (score 6):

The solution I found, was ridiculously simple. The suggestion (made [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10554138/how-to-make-sure-a-sms-went-through-after-sending-it-with-twilio)) was to hang on to the message id. I discovered the GetSMSMessage method on TwilioRestClient. So querying message status some time after sending will give you the updated status.

Comment: this method is deprecated now, use GetMessage instead

Answer (score 0):

By the way, the one thing you'll want to watch out for is that if you query the API too soon, you might get a status of "queued" or "sending" rather than "sent" or "failed", so be sure that your logic is set up to handle [these other possible responses](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sms#sms-status-values).

Also good to keep in mind that if you try to send more than 1 message per-second via a Twilio phone number, [Twilio will queue the excess messages and release them at a rate of 1 message per-second per-number](http://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/how-quickly-can-i-send-sms-messages). This comes into play because if you have a burst where you send 10 messages in 1 second, but then you go to retrieve the status of the messages after 5 seconds half of the messages will be "sent" and half will be "queued".

Answer (score 0):

If you dont have a callback url. Just call the method

```
TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

var message = MessageResource.Create(
            body: "Join Earth's mightiest heroes. Like Kevin Bacon.",
            from: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber(fromNumber),
            to: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber(toNumber)
        );

Console.WriteLine(message.Sid);

//Get the status from twilio
TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

var verificationCheck = MessageResource.Fetch(message.Sid);

Console.WriteLine(verificationCheck.Status);
```

where Sid is the id you get back from Twilio.